How to handle error in express while using mysql2 module
//auth router.js

const express = require("express");
const authService = require("../service/AuthService.js");

const router = express.Router();


router.post('/signup',async function(req, res,next){ 
    try{
    const body = req.body;
    const params = [body.email,body.password,body.nickname];
    const rst = await authService.signup(params);
    

    
    res.status(200);
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
        next(err);
        res.status(404).send("duplicated email address");
    }
    
})

module.exports = router;

// authService.js

const memberRepository = require("../repository/memberRepository");
const {v4: uuidv4} = require("uuid");
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const redis = require('redis');

dotenv.config();

const redisClient = redis.createClient({legacyMode: true});
redisClient.on('connect', () => {
    console.info('RedisConnected!')
})

redisClient.connect().then();

redisClient.auth(1234);

const redisCli = redisClient.v4;

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host:"smtp.gmail.com",
    port:587,
    auth:{
        user:'',
        pass: ''
    }
});

class AuthService{


     signup(params){
        try{
            return  memberRepository.signup(params);
        }catch(err){
            console.log("eqrwqrqrqrq");
        }   
    }

}
const authService = new AuthService();
module.exports = authService;

const db = require("../config/mysql.js");

class MemberRepository{

     signup(params){
        
        const sql = "insert into MEMBER (email,pw,nickname) values(?,?,?)";
        const conn =db.init();
        try{
            
            conn.query(sql, params ,function(err,result){
            
                if(err){
                    //console.log("query is not excuted: "+ err);
                    console.log('rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr');
                    return;
                }
                else{
                    return result;
                }
            });

            const [result] =  conn.execute(sql,params);
            return result;
        }catch(err){
            console.log('fffff');
            return {code:500 , message:'eeeee'}
        }finally{
             conn.end();
        }

       
    }


}




const memberRepository = new MemberRepository;

module.exports = memberRepository;

I am trying to make signup function in express
but it doesn't handle an error well 
when I signup with exsiting email 
express server shows error message like
RedisConnected!
fffff
{ code: 500, message: 'eeeee' }
rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr
node:events:496
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Duplicate entry '' for key 'MEMBER.email'
    at Packet.asError (/home/wo/DEV/CodeComm_front/CodeComm_front/code_comm_back/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packets/packet.js:738:17)
    at Execute.execute (/home/wo/DEV/CodeComm_front/CodeComm_front/code_comm_back/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/command.js:29:26)
    at Connection.handlePacket (/home/wo/DEV/CodeComm_front/CodeComm_front/code_comm_back/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:481:34)
    at PacketParser.onPacket (/home/wo/DEV/CodeComm_front/CodeComm_front/code_comm_back/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:97:12)
    at PacketParser.executeStart (/home/wo/DEV/CodeComm_front/CodeComm_front/code_comm_back/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js:75:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/wo/DEV/CodeComm_front/CodeComm_front/code_comm_back/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:104:25)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:559:12)
    at readableAddChunkPushByteMode (node:internal/streams/readable:510:3)
    at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:390:5)
Emitted 'error' event on Connection instance at:
    at Connection._notifyError (/home/wo/DEV/CodeComm_front/CodeComm_front/code_comm_back/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:252:12)
    at Connection._handleFatalError (/home/wo/DEV/CodeComm_front/CodeComm_front/code_comm_back/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:183:10)
    at Connection.handlePacket (/home/wo/DEV/CodeComm_front/CodeComm_front/code_comm_back/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:491:12)
    at PacketParser.onPacket (/home/wo/DEV/CodeComm_front/CodeComm_front/code_comm_back/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:97:12)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:390:5) {
  code: 'ER_DUP_ENTRY',
  errno: 1062,
  sqlState: '23000',
  sqlMessage: "Duplicate entry '' for key 'MEMBER.email'",
  sql: 'insert into MEMBER (email,pw,nickname) values(?,?,?)',
  fatal: true
}

and the server shutting down
I tried to add a code like
 process.on('unhandleRejection', (err, result) => {
    err.message, err.code, err.stack
 })

 process.on('uncaughtException', (err, result) => {
    err.message, err.code, err.stack
})

in app.js
But axios can't receive response from express server.
for example when I send request to server 5 times by axios, the server just hold the responses and if server shutting down ,
server send responses 5 times to axios of front end

The reason for server shutdown because your function is called after everything done asynchronously.
You don't need both callback and promise type query execution method, use any one.
const db = require("../config/mysql.js");

class MemberRepository{

     signup(params){
        
        const sql = "insert into MEMBER (email,pw,nickname) values(?,?,?)";
        const conn = db.init();
        try{    
            return conn.execute(sql,params);
        }catch(err){
            console.log('fffff');
            return {code:500 , message:'eeeee'}
        }finally{
             conn.end();
        }

       
    }


}

const memberRepository = new MemberRepository();

module.exports = memberRepository;


I changed the code the way you told me but still server shut down...

This time also the same error ? could you share the error ?

This time error also same

Try to remove passing error to next function (next(err);) since you are handling that. This might resolve your issue.

OK i will try it
